# how to add a new key value to the same key in an object in JavaScript based on a condition?

Tags: javascript

I have done it using ...qqParam['queryParams'] but is this the right approach?

```js
const qqParam = {};
if (view) {
  qqParam['queryParams'] = { view: view };
}
if (productNumber) {
  qqParam['queryParams'] = { ...qqParam['queryParams'], mode: 'productNumber' }; 
}
```

Comment: Seems overkill. Just do `qqParam['queryParams'].mode = 'productNumber';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is correct, just a couple things that can simplify your code while keeping it readable:

1. if you know you'll always need `queryParam` attribute, you can call it like this: `qqParam.queryParam` without the `[]`, if the key of the attribute is dynamic then you're doing it ok by passing it as a variable `qqParam[variable]`.
2. you're in both ifs modifying the same value so you might consider doing that on one statement:

`qqParam.queryParams = {`

`...(view && {view}),`

`...(productNumber && {mode:'productMode' })`

`};`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution but I get TS2339: Property 'queryParams' does not exist on type '{}' error if I change square brackets to qqParam.queryParams.

Comment: that's typescript trying to guess the type. If you just want to ignore that and don't have an specific type, you can do `const qqParam:any = {}` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code works but you can simplify it.

You don't need to use the square brackets when assigning a property to the object unless it contains a symbol, a special character or a computed property name.

```
const qqParam = {};

if(view) {
    qqParam.queryParams = { view };
}

if(productNumber) {
    qqParam.queryParams = { ...qqParam.queryParams, mode: 'productNumber' }; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution but I get TS2339: Property 'queryParams' does not exist on type '{}' error if I change square brackets to qqParam.queryParams.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. one improve that you can do is not to use : {'view' : view}.
you can just use {view} as the default key will be the value name when you not specifing one.

Also, i guess that 'productNumber' should be the variable productNumber and not the string 'productNumber'.

```
const qqParam = {};
if (view) {
   qqParam['queryParams'] = { view };
}
if (productNumber) {
   qqParam['queryParams'] = { ...qqParam['queryParams'], mode: productNumber }; 
}
```